# How can I convert an IPv4Address to char in omnet++(inet)?

Tags: omnet++, inet

How can I convert an `IPv4Address` to `char` in omnet++(inet)?
I want to use emit() and i need to cast ipv4Address into one of types are available with emit().

Comment: I seem to remember that this is usually just raw C++ code? Have a look at the ipv4Address object and see what it has in there to help you. If you still get stuck, update your answer with more information about what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the [definition of IPv4Address in the source code of INET v2.99.1](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/v2.99.1/src/inet/networklayer/contract/ipv4/IPv4Address.h#L192), I would say that its `str()` method can provide the text representation as a `std::string`. If you need a `char*` you can call [the string's `c_str()` method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).